# SQL Availability Group restore database to standalone server

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore, hadr

Running: SQL Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2

I want to test a backup by restoring onto an isolated server. The backup was taken from an Availability Group (HADR) configuration, but the target server does not have the clustering/HADR configuration and I don't want to have to set that up.

When I try to perform the restore, this following is returned:

```
Could not process the operation. AlwaysOn Availability Groups replica manager is disabled on this instance of SQL Server. Enable AlwaysOn Availability Groups, by using the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Then, restart the SQL Server service, and retry the currently operation. For information about how to enable and disable AlwaysOn Availability Groups, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

The message makes sense and I understand it, but have no way to take it out of an AG that doesn't exist on my target, and can't exist due to no cluster, etc.

Is there a way to make this scenario work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the error you get when you restore the master database from a server with AlwaysOn Availability Groups configured, or try to restore additional user databases onto a server that had the master database from an AG replica restored.

Don't restore the master database from an AG replica onto a different SQL Server as the master database.

If you absolutely have to restore master to get user objects out of it, restore it as a different database (like master_old) and then transfer the objects you need.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. I started over with a clean slate without restoring the master, and the AG databases restores worked perfectly. Thank you!