# Restoring a database that belonged to an AG

Tags: sql-server, restore, availability-groups

I'm trying to perfect our disaster recovery steps...

We take backups of a database that, in production, is in an AG.  It is the only database in the AG.

If we lose the building, I need to be able to restore it to a new instance.  Initially, for time's sake, this instance would not be running in an AG.

Of course, if you try a normal restore, you get error Msg 3104: "RESTORE cannot operate on database 'SI_EDI_PRD' because it is configured for database mirroring or has joined an availability group."

And, since the instance is not configured for AlwaysOn, you can't try to run the ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP command.

How can one restore this database??

Comment: If you loose the bulding, depending on if your AG is in Sync or Async mode, why cant you failover to secondary ? Your application will be using the listener name, so the end users will only get a timeout and will reconnect it again. In the background, you can start provisioning a new server, add it to cluster and configure AlwaysON and join the db to the Availability group.

Comment: @Kin Say the entire cluster gets wiped out.  For that matter, let's say we are restoring this database to a Dev server, for development.

Comment: Where are you attempting to run this restore statement?  If you run the `RESTORE DATABASE` on an instance where the database exists and is already part of an availability group, you'll certainly get this error.

Comment: @Max Hi, thanks...I'm restoring it on a totally separate instance...However, the instance is named the same, so that the system databases can be restored on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Brent answered it in a thread I hadn't seen:
[SQL Availability Group restore database to standalone server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106931/sql-availability-group-restore-database-to-standalone-server?rq=1)

Short answer: Don't restore the master database of an AG.

I'm not happy with this....But it'll do.

Thanks, everyone!